# cordova + browser platform + camera captures only part of Image

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Having problems with image capture for Browser platform for Cordova,  only the upper part of the image gets captured.

Using the example given on the official cordova camera page , issue happens only for Browser platform works proper for Android build.
Using image capture as Base64 as only same is supported for Browser platform.

I am using the full example as shown page below :
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

1) First had used ng-cordova as am using Angularjs in my actual project .
  had faced issue first there.
2) Tried imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist for angularjs , didnt work.
3) So created sample cordova project with only required plugins

1. when for same project was build for Android whole image as displayed while clicking the image was displayed and retrieved
2. for Browser only top part of image as retrieved as base64  format.

i am using extracting and using package.zip created "platforms\browser\build" folder post command " cordova build browser"

Comment: did you find the solution ? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple css tweak. On the line below:

```
 <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
```

Get rid of "width:60px;height:60px;"

That should resolve your problem.